# How do I use a pre-set list of choices from a foreign key as the options to select from in a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models, one is a profile user model and the other for categories of that profile. (see below). The category model has one 'name' attribute which consists of a  set of choices that users must choose as their profile type.

```
class DkUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)


CATEGORIES = (
             ('cat1', 'Category1'),
             ('cat2', 'Category2'),
             ('cat3', 'Category3'),
             )

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORIES)
```

My form thus far:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
  category = forms.ChoiceField()
  class Meta:
        model = DkUser
        fields = ('category')
```

What I'm trying to do is to include a drop-down choice-field on the form that allows users to select one of 'category 1', 'category 2' or 'category3'.

I've looked at ModelChoiceField, but that appears to be for choosing from the Model Instances.

How might I achieve this? All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to edit the `Category` model from a form for `DkUser`. Are you sure you don't want to just select a category for the user instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need to have a ProfileForm defined, and what you need is to have a **str** method for your Category model, and django will do everything for you. As far as i know following should work as you want:

```
class DkUser(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   category=models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)

CATEGORIES = (
         ('cat1', 'Category1'),
         ('cat2', 'Category2'),
         ('cat3', 'Category3'),
  )

class Category(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORIES)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And on Admin page you should see a combo-box for category field for DKUser model.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, it is associating the the Category model with the DkUser Model, but I think what I need to do is to actually create instances of each of those categories in order for it to have something to choose from. Is there a way to initialize each of the CATEGORY choices within the model and then repeatedly select from those initialized models?

Comment: Django Admin will add the + button near the category field, when you look to DkUser. So you can add a view. But let me ask in this case why you need to have separate model for Category? why you just not keep it only in single model DkUser and provide a list of Categories directly instead of foreignkey